# Interrupt boot from systemd (and/or SysV) unit

Tags: systemd, sysvinit

I am currently creating a daemon that is supposed to help with management of Linux VMs. It needs to be able to hold the system in a state where it cannot be logged into, but has a network available. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new systemd target for these system maintenance activities, as it's likely that preventing users from logging in isn't the only system activity which needs to be altered. Have that target depend upon the default target, so that you don't change the current graphics mode or log users out.

Create a new systemd service to prevent logins by creating or deleting the /etc/nologin file (see the use of pam_nologin in /etc/pam.d for how /etc/nologin works). Take care to delete only a /etc/nologin file which you created (eg, by checking for a magic string in the contents). Have that service to be WantedBy the new systemd target.

Even if you do this there will still be running "users", such as gdm displaying the login screen. Most VMs exist to support services other than a user login to a command line; for those you might need to de-enrole the machine from the load-sharing cluster. You need to be very clear about what you mean when you say "no users".

Experience with system updates has been that it is best to download and prepare them during normal operation, and then apply them as part of re-starting the system. Systemd has hooks for this which you could take advantage of. See the pkcon system for how they can be used.. You might want a "draining" state where you aren't given or don't permit new sessions (and that might happen automatically, as with detaching from a cluster, or that might need a new target, as described above).

There has been substantial work on the management of Linux VMs, with large communities around Ansible, Puppet and others. So I am a little surprised that you are writing yet another daemon.

Comment: I've tried to make other management systems work, but they don't do everything I want. Thanks for the advice, I'll look into it.

Comment: Also, the main purpose of it holding the system in this odd state is to contact a server to get deployment information, and wait to be configured.